# Memory error Python Staircase

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm writing a code for a Grok learning(website) test I've been testing my code on Mac(messed up schools should be using pc) and nothing seems to appear for about 1 min then my web page reloads and this appears in the area where the code displays it's running form:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(" " * number + "|")
MemoryError
```

Can I get some help understanding this I've never seen it before?
(code below)

```
a=0
number = int(input("How many steps? "))
print("__")
if number != 1:
  while a < number:
    print(" " * number + "|")
    a = a + 1
    print(" " * number + "_")
    number = number * 2
elif number == 1:
  print("__|")
```

The code is for making a staircase using underscores and pipe characters from the user's input(screen shot of explanation included)

Comment: you increase `a` by one each step and double `number`  thus this is an infinite loop and that is why you get the `Memory Error`

Comment: Ye you've got an infinite loop going, which will eventually use all your memory and crash. It seems like number shouldn't be incrementing, since it is your baseline for the while loop

Comment: Also where is the screenshot?

Comment: sorry forgot to remove that i couldn't get the image in though i was able a week ago SO must have changed something

Comment: could you provide an example output then?

Comment: remove infinite loop got it

Comment: sorry web browser crashed

Comment: dhdavvie sorry I can't provide an output as I'm on mac and mac is bad and I can't copy and paste the output as it's a million blank lines then the problem output. again sorry

Comment: @Jako613 I don't want your program output, I need the desired output :p

Comment: @Jako613 based on a guess of your desired output, ive written up an answer and explained the thought process

Comment: thx I didn't realise what you wanted you just said could you provide an example output not thinking of the proper example given to me. and what you thought was right actually thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming this is desired output for input of 4:

```
How many steps? 4
__
  |__
     |__
        |__
___________|
```

You can do it like this:

```
number = int(input("How many steps? "))
print("__")
for a in range(1, number):
    offset = a*2 + a - 1
    print(" " * (offset) + '|' + ('__' if a < number else ''))
offset = number*2 + number - 1
print("_" * (offset) + '|')
```

Basically you can get rid of the `number != 1` check at the beginning since it should behave identically for any input. You then loop over the number of steps. At each step you get the offset, which is twice the step number (a), plus the offset from the previous pipe chars. You then check if there is a step after this one, so you can put the underscores on the same line. Finally, on the last step (which is outside the for loop), you just put all underscore instead of whitespace and the final pipe char

Comment: hey I tried and edited the code because it turns out you had an extra space in your code making this:

Comment: @Jako613 The extra space was due to me having to guess the desired output, as I guessed that each step had 2 underscores instead of 1.

Comment: again sorry i couldn't comprehends what you were aking of me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version (which is also the way how Grok Learning recommends to do it).

```
n = int(input("How many steps? "))
print("__")
for i in range(n - 1):
  print('  '*(i + 1) + "|_")
print("__"*n + "|")
```

I hope this helps!